# Using column names in ggparcoord

Tags: r, ggally

I have a really basic problem with ggparcoord plot function from Ggally package. On this site https://r-graph-gallery.com/parallel-plot-ggally.html there is the following code for the "most basic" plot, which works fine:

```
# Libraries
library(GGally)

# Data set is provided by R natively
data <- iris

# Plot
ggparcoord(data,
    columns = 1:4, groupColumn = 5
    )
```

I'm just not able to **use the column names instead** and **to use a specific order** like:

```
# Libraries
library(GGally)

# Data set is provided by R natively
data <- iris

# Plot
ggparcoord(data,
    columns = c('Petal.Width', 'Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Sepal.Length'), groupColumn = 'Species',
    )
```

I get the **error**: "invalid value for order; must either be a vector of column indices or one of 'skewness', 'allClass' ..."

I found a solution with column indices to use something like

```
columns = c(4, 2, 3, 1)
```

Is there no standard way to use column names for this plot?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While both column names and indices actually [should work](https://ggobi.github.io/ggally/reference/ggparcoord.html) in current {GGally} versions, you could use `match` for a workaround:

```
match(c('Petal.Length', 'Sepal.Length'),
      names(iris)
)
```

```
[1] 3 1
```